# How to Add background image in canvas for android game application

Tags: android, image, animation, canvas

to learn the functionality of missile android game app, i thought of doing some changes to it, so started up the editing of background change, i had googled and placed the code in canvas,

```
 Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap( 0, 0, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);

     c.drawBitmap(background, 10, 010, null);
```

i had tried many things but nothing worked out, and also here in the above code not given the path for drawable, where should i give the path for image?
any helps plz..

Comment: You means you are trying to use your Drawable resource to getting in Bitmap and drawing in canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will give you some clue about this...

```
//Here you can decode it from any source like SD card as i shown,Resources or from assets
    Bitmap mBitmapFromSdcard = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/download/tux.png");
    Canvas mCanvas = canvas;
            if (mBitmapFromSdcard != null) {
                mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapFromSdcard, 0, 0, null);
            }
```